# How to get Thunderbird to collect addresses from not-already-downloaded IMAP messages?

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap, address-book

I've created a new Thunderbird account to work with an IMAP account of mine on some mail server. I have all the message headers downloaded now, not all the bodies, and have read a couple of messages. Unfortunately, Thunderbird's 'Collected Addresses' only seems to include addresses from the few messages I've read or written, not from all messages whose headers have been downloaded.

- Is there some configuration value I can change to make Thunderbird look for addresses in all of my headers?
- Is there perhaps some 'manual' way to collect these addresses, say into `abook.mab`?

Comment: see this: https://superuser.com/questions/353181/how-to-copy-all-email-addresses-from-an-email-in-thunderbird

Comment: @Turbine: That doesn't help, that question regards a single message.

Answer (score 3):

The [Email Address Crawler Plugin](https://nic-nac-project.org/~kaosmos/index-en.html#eac) might work. Note that the [earlier version](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/email-address-crawler/) is no longer maintained. To use the updated version:

1. Follow the [direct download link](https://nic-nac-project.org/~kaosmos/emailcrawler-5.1.2.xpi). (**Attention** this is not approved by Mozila jet, see comment below)
2. Start Thunderbird (v31.0 or greater).
3. Open the triple-bar menu (**≡**).
4. Click **Add-ons**.
5. Click the icon beside the search text box to open a drop-down menu.
6. Select **Install Add-on From File...***
7. Browse to the download location for Email Crawler.
8. Select the file (e.g., `emailcrawler-5.1.2.xpi`).
9. Click **Open**.
10. Click **Install Now**.
11. Click **Restart Now**.

Then:

1. Right-click on any folder.
2. Select **Crawl folder for email addresses**.
3. Check **To** and **From**.
4. Set **Choose a [sic] addressbook as a target for the found addresses** to `Collected Addresses`.
5. Optionally, set **Needed # of occurrences** to `2` (to help filter invalid addresses).
6. Click **OK**.

---

If you want to use an approved Plugin from Moxilla Add-On Page, maybe the [Email Address Crawler Plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/email-address-crawler/) is a solution for you?

> EMail Address Crawler *by CySlider*
>   Automatically fill your address books or send mass mails with e-mail 
>   addresses extracted from all your e-mails.

It is a bit outdated, but there is stated by someone it that still worked in 17.0, so maybe it still works in Thunderbird 31

Comment: I need to try it. On first appearance, it looks like it should work with TB 24.x , but now I need to create a new account with no messages downloaded, to test it.

Comment: *EMail Address Crawler 3* did not work for me using Thunderbird v31.

Comment: Emailcrawler would be a good choice, but the Mozilla approved plugin version does not work with recent TBird. (2015 february).

Comment: Emailcrawler works with TB 45. The new URL is: https://freeshell.de//~kaosmos/index-en.html#eac -- make note that you have to left+click, then right-click before selecting "Crawl folder", otherwise it will crawl the previously selected folder.

Comment: 5.1.2 Not working with TB 60.6.1

Answer (score 1):

I founded one that worked well here: **EmailPicky 4** (search for it in Mozilla Add-On Page)

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/emailpicky-4/

Comment: The description talks about getting information from downloaded messages, but doesn't mention anything about getting it from the server for messages that aren't in Thunderbird.  Are you sure this does what's asked in the question?

Comment: "Is there some configuration value I can change to make Thunderbird look for addresses in all of my headers?" He is not asking for messages which aren't in Thunderbird, but for messages which headers were downloaded. For what I tried, this plugin works for this matter.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a workaround:

- go in **offline mode** and stay offline during this whole process until you are done
- create a filter that **replies** to all emails and run it
- delete all those mails from your out box before you send any
- make sure there are no more mails in your outbox before you go online again

Thought, this could move all contacts into your collected addresses

## But this doesn't work!

I tried it, and the addresses are not collected until you really send them

I will keep this here for reference.
Maybe this answer gives an idea on how to create a workaround that works using the built-in filters. **Maybe with forwarding** somehow. Or with a fake mailserver that just **pretends** to send the mails.

Comment: I dunno, you run the risk of sending out those replies by mistake at some point. Also, I'll need to reapply that procedure repeatedly...

Answer (score 0):

**It is SIMPLE to do that:**

Thunderbird stores all messages in a folder (like inbox, sent, trash, etc) in a single "text" file. Just pass that file through [Power Email Address Extractor](http://www.soft.tahionic.com/download-web-extractor/index.html). It will collect all emails in that file.

The program is VERY flexible. It has special filters for Thunderbird files. So, if you want you can extract emails only from "to", "from", "cc" fields.

Comment: While doing that is possible workaround, it's not what I asked; I want _Thunderbird_ to do it...

Comment: windows only :(